# Post to a server writen in Hapijs from wordpress using wp_remote_post

Tags: wp-remote-post

I'm trying to post to a server written in Hapijs from wordpress using wp_remote_post.

I'm getting connection refused and I can't figure out what is wrong.

The server is on port 8080.

Nb:wp_remote_get doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

After further look into the problem I found out that for a weird reason wordpress only allows posting to port 80. Otherwise the post is denied.

In other words, the server you are posting to must be listening on port 80.